Get Named Credential to use local url or override the URL
I have a connected app that can be configured with a named credential, allowing users to send API messages to their respective Salesforce orgs. However, I'm concerned that each time I transition from development to partial, UAT, or production environments, I'll need to manually reconfigure the named credential to point to the "new" connected app and org. This is because the org's domain might have changed (dev/prod), and the app will have a different client ID. Is there a way to automate this process? Ideally, it would involve querying the connected app for the client ID and retrieving the current org domain to establish the connection automatically.

Perhaps consider the new External Client Apps instead? Not sure it would resolve your issue, but worth a look perhaps.

Is it possible that this could work similarly to Record Type Ids behaviour? Once they get to specific org, each sandbox refresh from that org will preserve the id. Similarly the connected app, once in prod, would preserve its id down to refreshed orgs.
